# SRVE0260E "cannot use error page", renders exception in html, but shouldn't

Tags: java, error-handling, websphere

I've got a stack trace shown in the web page in the browser. This isn't supposed to happen. All errors should be directed to error pages. My web.xml contains:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/errors/404.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errors/500.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Those two error pages work; I can visit them, and they show the message they should show.

But on one particular page, an error gets rendered in my html. Note in particular the line: **`SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.`** What does that mean? *Why* can't use that error page (it exists!), and why does it render the error on my page instead?

Complete error with stacktrace below:

```
Error Page Exception
SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.

Original Exception:
Error Message: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'fooItems' on type nl.mydomain.foo.fooHelperBean
Error Code: 500
Target Servlet:
Error Stack:
javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'fooItems' on type nl.mydomain.foo.fooHelperBean
 at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:69)
 at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
 at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:102)
 at org.apache.el.parser.AstEmpty.getValue(AstEmpty.java:29)
 at org.apache.el.parser.AstNot.getValue(AstNot.java:26)
 at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:263)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:774)
 at com.ibm._jsp._glossary_2D_query._jspx_meth_c_if_2(_glossary_2D_query.java:994)
 at com.ibm._jsp._glossary_2D_query._jspService(_glossary_2D_query.java:197)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:732)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
 at nl.mydomain.common.TimingInternalResourceViewResolver$1.render(TimingInternalResourceViewResolver.java:34)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:732)
 at nl.mydomain.util.RenderUtils.dispatchBufferedRequest(RenderUtils.java:119)
 at nl.mydomain.util.RenderUtils.getResponse(RenderUtils.java:312)
 at nl.mydomain.util.RenderUtils.renderComponentPresentation(RenderUtils.java:95)
 at nl.mydomain.util.RenderUtils.renderComponentPresentations(RenderUtils.java:75)
 at nl.mydomain.tags.ComponentPresentationsTag.doTag(ComponentPresentationsTag.java:84)
 at com.ibm._jsp._standard._jspx_meth_cds_componentpresentations_0(_standard.java:388)
 at com.ibm._jsp._standard._jspService(_standard.java:176)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:374)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
 at mydomain.common.TimingInternalResourceViewResolver$1.render(TimingInternalResourceViewResolver.java:34)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at nl.mydomain.interceptors.DevPartyIdCookieFilter.doFilter(DevPartyIdCookieFilter.java:70)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at nl.mydomain.foo.FooHelperBean.getFooItems(FooHelperBean.java:51)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
 at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:65)
 ... 109 more



Error Page Exception:
Error Message: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed.
Error Code: 0
Target Servlet:
Error Stack:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed.
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1189)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1171)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:141)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendError(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:141)
 at nl.mydomain.controller.PageController.showPage(PageController.java:101)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor267.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:732)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.sendError(WebApp.java:3396)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:744)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:229)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
 at nl.mydomain.common.TimingInternalResourceViewResolver$1.render(TimingInternalResourceViewResolver.java:34)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.include(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:732)
 at nl.mydomain.util.RenderUtils.dispatchBufferedRequest(RenderUtils.java:119)
 at nl.mydomain.util.RenderUtils.getResponse(RenderUtils.java:312)
 at nl.mydomain.util.RenderUtils.renderComponentPresentation(RenderUtils.java:95)
 at nl.mydomain.util.RenderUtils.renderComponentPresentations(RenderUtils.java:75)
 at nl.mydomain.tags.ComponentPresentationsTag.doTag(ComponentPresentationsTag.java:84)
 at com.ibm._jsp._standard._jspx_meth_cds_componentpresentations_0(_standard.java:388)
 at com.ibm._jsp._standard._jspService(_standard.java:176)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:99)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
 at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:121)
 at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:259)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:374)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
 at nl.mydomain.common.TimingInternalResourceViewResolver$1.render(TimingInternalResourceViewResolver.java:34)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
 at nl.mydomain.interceptors.DevPartyIdCookieFilter.doFilter(DevPartyIdCookieFilter.java:70)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
 at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
 at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
 at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
 at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:277)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
 at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
 at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
 at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
 at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)
```

This not supposed to be possible. Of course exceptions can occur, but they should never be shown to the user. So why does this happen? What's doing this and how can I stop it? It should simply be redirecting to the error page, and logging the exception. It should never, ever show the exception to the user.

Note that my problem is not the exception itself. I can probably solve that on my own. The real problem, which is far more serious, is that the exception is shown to the user. Why does that happen?

Comment: Does WS serve these pages directly or is these some additional Spring configuration that designates them (or `/errors/` path) as static resources?

Comment: The /errors/ path is not static; these error pages come from a Tridion CMS. There is a pile of configuration files that I know very little about, but apart from the web.xml, I can find practically nothing that seems to do anything with errors. Do you have anything specific I should be looking for?